# Json result "undefined" when attempting to dynamically populate select list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am attempting to add dynamic rows with a product and a price to an order form with Jquery. The issue is that I need the product dropdown to be dynamically filled from mysql. The rows are adding correctly. The only problem I am having how is that the dropdown menu only has one option and that option says "undefined".

**EDIT 1 :** I changed the PHP code. I think it is formatted correctly now but I am still getting "undefined" in my select list.

**EDIT 2 :** I tested the php and there were some errors. Now the php works perfectly on its own and returns the following json encoded array, but when I am attempting to pull it into my jquery script it is still returning an "undefined" result. :

```
[{"product":"wedding 4","price":"400.00","id":"9"},
 {"product":"wedding 2 ","price":"400.00","id":"8"},
 {"product":"Wedding 1","price":"4000.00","id":"1"},
 {"product":"potato","price":"50.00","id":"6"},
 {"product":"Event","price":"3000.00","id":"5"},
 {"product":"alligator","price":"800.00","id":"7"}]
```

jQuery:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('p#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    $('#addingContainer').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<label>Product or Service</label><select id="product_' + count + '" name="products[]'+ '" >');

$.get('includes/productrow.php', function(data){
$('#product_' + count + '').append('<option value=' + data.product_id + ' data-price=' + data.price + '>' + data.product +'</option>');
});

$('#addingContainer').append('</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Price</label><input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" name="prices[]' + '" class="price" >');
});
```

productrow.php

```
<?php  
    $productSql = "SELECT product_id, product, price FROM products WHERE compid = '$compid' ORDER BY product desc";
    $productResult = mysql_query($productSql, $link);

    while($productRow = mysql_fetch_array($productResult)){
    $final_array[] = array("product" => $productRow['product'], "price" =>   $productRow['price'], "id" => $productRow['id']);
    };

    echo json_encode($final_array);


?>
```

** Disclaimer, I know I should be using PDO and as soon as this project is finished I will begin using it.

Comment: You should neither be using PHP-MySQL nor PHP-MySQLi they are both no good now it is deprecated and will be dropped in the next release

Comment: @Developer106 What makes you think `mysqli` extension is deprecated?

Comment: I don;t fully understand your use case. If you want the drop down populated dynamically at page load, there is no need for javascript/jQuery to do this.  Are you trying to add additional options to the dropdown after the page load?

Comment: @MikeBrant There will not be anything there at page load. The user clicks the "add" link to add the product rows to the page and at that point the dropdown will need to be dynamically populated.

Comment: No I meant MySQL with the deprecated thing, MySQLi, is just not so good, and you should better off use PDO, Gives more abstraction to the Database Layer.

Answer (score 2):

I always use jquerys $.get:

```
$.get('includes/productrow.php', function(resp){
   $('#yourid').append(resp);
});
```

Try if you could implement this.

Use it like this:

```
$.get('includes/productrow.php', function(resp){
   $('#addingContainer').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<label>Product or Service</label><select id="product_' + count + '" name="products[]'+ '" /><option value=""></option>' + resp + '</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Price</label><input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" name="prices[]' + '" class="price" >');
});
```

Hope this works!

I made the following files to test it:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../server/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('productrow.php', function(resp){
               $('body').append('<strong>Link #</strong><br />' + '<label>Product or Service</label><select id="product_" name="products[]'+ '" /><option value=""></option>' + resp + '</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Price</label><input type="text" id="price_" name="prices[]' + '" class="price" >');
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

productrow.php:

```
<?php
echo "test";
```

result:

```
Link #
Product or Servicetest  Price
```

the test is there as expected. Could you send me your whole code or create a jsfiddle

Comment: Where would i add this so that it would fill the options of the select?

Comment: This worked in that it made the jquery functionality work again, the rows are being added correctly, but it is still showing an empty select. Not even the blank `<option value=""></option>` is not showing up.

Comment: @PaigeRoseFigueira Are you getting any errors if you inspect element? How are you calling the $.get function? if you want it when the page loads you should use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: That's what's frustrating! No errors at all! I am calling it with the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @PaigeRoseFigueira Hmm let me try something i'll respond in a few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61065/discussion-between-paige-rose-figueira-and-stijn-bernards).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the JSON request. The corrected code is below. This code also allows a text field with the price of the product to be automatically populated using the data-price attribute:

Jquery:

```
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

$('p#add_field').click(function(){

    count += 1;

    $('#addingContainer').append('<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' + '<label>Product or Service</label><select id="product_' + count + '" name="products[]'+ '" ><option value=""></option>');

    $.getJSON('includes/productrow.php', function(data){
            var select = $('#product_' + count + '');
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $('<option/>').attr('value', val.product_id)
                              .attr('data-price', val.price)
                              .html(val.product)
                              .appendTo(select);
    });

    $('#addingContainer').append('</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Price</label><input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" name="prices[]' + '" class="price" >');
    });
```

productrow.php

```
$productSql = "SELECT product_id, product, price, compid FROM products WHERE compid = '$compid' ORDER BY product desc";
$productResult = mysql_query($productSql, $link);

while($productRow = mysql_fetch_array($productResult)){
$final_array[] = array("product" => $productRow['product'], "price" =>     $productRow['price'], "id" => $productRow['product_id']);
};

echo json_encode($final_array);
```